# Granting exchange system manager permissions 2003

Tags: exchange-2003

We have a remote Admin group with control over their own OU, they can manage AD accounts and Exchange accounts in this OU. I need for them to be able to move exchange mailboxes from one mail-store to another only on their dedicated Exchange. Is it possible for them to use Exchange System Manager from their desktops with full functionality? have 5 other exchange servers we don't want them to manage.

Other than giving them local admin rights to their exchange server what other options do I have?

Thank you,

Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so no one answered my question... Here is what I found out that works. Create a security group, add your users. On the Exchange server you want them to have access right click it while using the Exchange system manager and give this groups permissions in the security taps. I gave them everything but full control.

Hope this helps anyone having the same issues.